# Client/Server communication via internet

Tags: sockets, upnp

Which is the best solution to communicate bidirectionally  between a 
remote server and a client behind an internet box?

1. UPnP with Sockets.
2. HTTPS/Database Server and the client make 1 request every Xsec to know 
   if there is new data.
3. Client opens 1 connection on the server and it maintains open to make a 
   tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the application (though you can immediately rule out UPnP, which is an ugly hack suitable for local networks only.) Start reading about the Internet foundation set of protocols - the [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcp/ip), pick up the [Stevens book](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html) - you will get a much better understanding of your options.

Comment: My application is very simple. It's a Client/Server architecture. 
1 client/Server on the Web which listen and send commands from/to customer PC.
Many client/server on the customer PC which listen and send commands from/to the web.

Which is the best way to make a distributed architecture over the web?